# No stdout from jupyter javascript

Tags: javascript, jupyter

I am building Jupyter notebook and can not get stdout from a python function 
that I call from the OnClick attribute of a javascript button form.

```
onclick='main_task_bar_system_callback()'

function main_task_bar_system_callback(){
var command = "handle_main_button_bar_click_system()";      
console.log(command);
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
kernel.execute(command);
```

all commands in python handler below fail

```
def handle_main_button_bar_click_system() :

clear_screen()
display_main_task_bar()
show_sys_info()
print("system clicked")


def show_sys_info():

import sys
syspath = sys.path
print("\nSystem Path : ")
for i in range(len(syspath)) :
if(i > 0) :
print("    ",syspath[i])

print("\nVersion : \n    ",sys.version)
print("\nAPI : ",sys.api_version)    
print("\nVersion Info : \n    ",sys.version_info,"\n")
```

Everything works fine as far as the calls trail goes in that I am sure that 
the show_sys_info() gets called when the appropriate button is clicked. I 
tested by putting a load web page in my show_sys_info and it works fine.

My specific problem is that all of my prints, clear_output() show no output 
to the Jupyter code cell output. I have tried every flavor print, display, 
write ... and none generate output to the code cell output.

I can call the show_sys_info function directly from the code_cell and all 
is well. I also defined an ipywidget button widget and can call the 
show_sys_info and everything works fine.

It just seems that any call via javascript loses stdout and the code cell 
output area.

I use the below to display my button form and load the corresponnding 
javascript

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import display
display(HTML(get_button_group_form(main_task_bar_keyTitleList,
                                   main_task_bar_jsList,
                                   main_task_bar_javascript)))
```